# How do I get Python to spit out all defined values for an argument/kwarg?

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, python-module, keyword-argument

I am building a simple GUI using TkInter, and I'd like to have Python tell me all available options that I can configure Cursors to, e.g.: button.config(Cursor="cross").

I know I could just find a list on a tutorial or documentation somewhere, but my thinking is that I'd be better off knowing how to get Python to tell me itself... Give a man a fish etc.

I've done some research and tried to use dir(), getattr() and vars() as well as keys(). I'm guessing that at least one of those will get me what I want, but I'm confused by the sheer amount of stuff they spit out.

for example:

```
import tkinter as tk

b = tk.Button()

print('Using dir: ', dir(b))

print('Using getattr: ', getattr(b, 'config'))

print('Using vars: ', vars(b))

print('Using keys: ', b.keys())
```

Ideally, I'd like it to spit out an iterable that I can use to test/trial each available definition. I don't know whether this is possible, but since python/TkInter knows what I mean when I pass something like b.config(cursor='cross'), it's got to be listed somewhere, right?

As I said, the functions I tried spit out a bunch of methods and attributes I could give values, but not what values are available.

*edit: Here's the code I'd like to feed with the available Options, for this specific example.

```
import math
import tkinter as tk

w = tk.Tk()


def listify(event):

    c = 0

    all_options = entry.get()
    entry.destroy()
    list_options = all_options.split(" ")
    print(len(list_options))

    for value in list_options:
        lbl = tk.Label(text=value, cursor=value, bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED)
        rounded = int(math.floor(c / 20))

        r = c - 20 * rounded

        lbl.grid(column=rounded, row=r, pady=5,
                 padx=5, rowspan=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        c += 1


entry = tk.Entry()
entry.grid()
entry.bind('<Return>', listify)

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: `dir` should work or maybe even `b.__dict__` but what do want as the output?

Comment: @Jab using dir Returns a list containing 216 elements, and 'cursor' is one of them. But I what I want is a list or dictionary that contains all the predefined values I can assign to 'cursors' (in this example, but really, I want to learn how to do this for any module with values I can assign to attributes).

Comment: Calling `dir()` or `__dict__` on your object's classes won't give you accepted values for those attributes, just the attributes themselves. You might get from calling dir or dict that b.config has a `cursor`, but not what the code that parses that value considers as acceptable input (`cross`). You will find those listings in the code of the module you use. Or in the documentation. In the case of Tk's Button class, the `Cursor` manpages are [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/cursors.htm)

Comment: @BoboDarph thanks for your answer. I've understood as much, and I know that I could look through the documentation, but is there a way you know of that I can retrieve the listings in the command prompt?

Comment: Since Tkinter is a wrapper on top of Tcl/Tk, I would guess no. Not unless you want to make a module to get them yourself.

Comment: For tkinter widgets, "If you call the `.config()` method on a widget with no arguments, you'll get a dictionary of all the widget's current options." According to this [documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20181227153709id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Comment: @BoboDarph I'll look into that then.

Comment: @martineau yea, and that is useful, but I'd like to know what I can set those options to be. Obviously, some options take a numeric value (e.g. width), but things like anchor or font take specific strings/arguments.

Comment: You wrote "it's got to be listed somewhere, right?" Ah, sounds like you want documentation. `tkinter` is notoriously poorly documented. There are many websites and books that try to make up for that, and those are your best option.

Comment: There is nothing to tell you what values can be used with each option because in many cases the values are infinite.

Comment: @BryanOakley but is there really no feasible way to check whether or not there is a bank of predefined values somewhere? Being as absolutely specific as possible, in my example: Python knows what to do when I give it "cross", but it doesn't know what to do with "OompaLoompa", like this:`import tkinter as tk
b = tk.Button()
c = b.config(cursor="OompaLoompa")` A "try" Loop would tell me if its a possible Option, but would be extremely inefficient. I'd be testing for what I **can't** do, rather than what I can.

Comment: _"but is there really no feasible way to check whether or not there is a bank of predefined values somewhere?"_ - no, there is not. Not in any general sense. There are ways to get a list of colors, and there are ways to get a list of cursors, and a list of fonts, but each type of data requires a different method. For some options there is literally no way (values for `relief`, for example). There is nothing in tkinter or in tcl and tk that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every widget has a `configure` method which will return all of the configuration options for a widget.

When you call `configure` you get back a dictionary. The keys are the option names, the value is a tuple. The tuple will either have two values or five values.

**Two values**

If the dictionary element has two values, it represents an alias to another option. The values are as follows:

1. the name of the option (eg: "bd" for borderwidth)
2. the tcl/tk option that it is aliased to (e.g. "-borderwidth")

For example, for widgets with a `borderwidth` attribute, the result of `configure()` will have a key `"bd"` with the value `('bd', '-borderwidth')`.

**Five values**

If the dictionary element has five values, it is a normal option. The values are as follows:

1. The name of the option (e.g. "borderwidth")
2. The option database<sup>1</sup> name (e.g.  "borderWidth")
3. The option database class name (e.g. "BorderWidth")
4. The default value of the option
5. The currently configured value of the option

**Printing all options and their values**

You can iterate over this dictionary to print out the values by examing all values that have five elements. For example:

```
config = button.configure()
for option in sorted(config.keys()):
    if len(config[option]) == 5:
        print("{} = {}".format(option, config[option][5]))
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The option database is something that is mostly used on X11-based systems (i.e. not windows, not OSX). For an example of how to use the option database see [Changing the Default Font via the Option Database](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-option-database.htm) on effbot.

For a comprehensive overview of the option database see [Options and Tk - a Beginners Guide](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~fellowsd/tcl/option-tutorial.html). It is written from the perspective of a tcl programmer, but the concepts are applicable to tkinter.

Comment: hi Bryan, thanks for your answer. I think I may have been somewhat unclear in my phrasing of my question, so I've tried to clarify somewhat. Anyway, your answer is very helpful in that I now understand what the different values in the keys actually are. I've added the code that I ended up using to get an overview of the available config Options for Cursors in my Post. What I was hoping to get from this post is a function that Feeds all the Options, without the user having to copy-paste them in the entry. Instead, I want to be able to select an Attribute, and have it Show me the Options.